# How to add text from documents in a folder to an array

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

Good afternoon. Unfortunately, I did not find an answer to a simple question. I have a document folder. PDF format. I can use Pandas to open one document and add its text to an array. Where the first column is the folder name and the second is the text from the document. But how do you do this for all documents in a folder? Alas, I don't know.

| category | text |
| --- | --- |
| test | first document |
| test | second document |
| test | ... |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you put the code you already have into a function that takes in a file name and the DataFrame you have so far, it's pretty easy to do what you want:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame()

files = os.listdir("[path/to/folder/]")

for file in files:
    dataframe = addFileToTable(file, dataFrame)
```

If you're not sure how to add a new row to the dataframe:

```
def addFileToTable(file, dataframe):
    # Convert PDF to array
    # ...

    row = {"category" : array[0], "text" : array[1]}
    df = dataframe.append(row, ignore_index = True)
    return df
```

Comment: Oh thanks so much .  I'm so stupid

Comment: No worries, there can a learning curve to feel comfortable with pandas